# Passing a php array as a json element with json_encode in a hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to work with an array in javascript so I am trying to Json_encode my php array as a hidden value. This is giving me this error Notice: Array to string conversion in.. Is this not possible? Am I going about this wrong?

```
$pic_array = array();
$titles = array();
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}

echo "<input id='json_pics' type='hidden' value='json_encode($pic_array)'/>";
```

Comment: The json_encode has to be outside quotes, for php to execute it. `echo "<input id='json_pics' type='hidden' value='".json_encode($pic_array)."'/>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper code is

```
echo "<input id='json_pics' type='hidden' value='" . json_encode($pic_array) . "'/>";
```

In your current code php doesn't understand that you try to use `json_encode` function and just sees `$pic_array` variable which is array.

Answer (score 1):

For better readability I would recommand using `printf` for inserting the json encoded string.

```
echo sprintf("<input id='json_pics' type='hidden' value='%s'/>", json_encode($pic_array));
```